# Division errónea

Tags: javascript

Estaba armando una calculadora del IMC (indice de masa corporal) para practicar un poco.

**Estoy teniendo un problema con la función del IMC().**

Les paso el código:

```
function PuntuarMetros(numero){
    n = numero.toString();
    a = n.slice(0,1);
    b = a + "." + n.slice(1,3);
    return parseFloat(b);
}

function NumeroAlCuadrado(numero){
    //Agregar condicional si tiene o no "." o ","
    a = PuntuarMetros(numero);    
    b = a * a;
    c= b.toFixed(2);
    return parseFloat(c);
}

function DividirNumero(dividendo,divisor){
    a = dividendo;
    b = divisor;
    c = a / b;
    return c;
}

function IMC(peso,altura){
    a = peso;
    console.warn(a)
    b = NumeroAlCuadrado(altura);
    console.warn(b)
    c = DividirNumero(a,b);
    console.warn(c)
    return c;
}
```

Consola de Chrome:

```
DividirNumero(64,2.92)
21.91780821917808
64/2.92
21.91780821917808

IMC(64,171)
64
2.92
0.5856164383561644
```

Como bien se puede ver, cuando realizo la división de dos números mediante la función me da como resultado "21.9", luego pruebo dividirlo fuera de la función y me da el mismo resultado.

Ahora cuando lo hago dentro de la función de IMC, la división me la realiza de forma errónea.

Espero haya sido claro con mi problema.

Comment: Hola, me parece que estás teniendo problemas de ámbito. Acostumbra a declarar tus variables usando `let` o `const` dentro de tus funciones. El hecho de llamarlas todas con el mismo nombre (`a`, `b` y `c`) sin declararlas, hace que todas ellas sean elevadas (`hoisted`) al ámbito global, produciendo un comportamiento inesperado de tu aplicación. Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!

Tal cual como comentas, era ese mi error. Voy a pegar una leida a las variables Let y const. 

Muy amable encerio.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar cuál es la función de `PuntuarMetros` ?, no entiendo por qué utilizas tantas funciones extras, cuando simplemente puedes hacer `const IMC = (m, a) => m / (a * a)`

Comment: Hola Eduen! 

Lo hice mas que nada por si la persona que lo utilize coloca 171 metros. En este caso con la funcion quedaria 1.71. 

Es una tonteria jaja pero aprovecho y practico funciones y metodos del lenguaje.

Comment: No coloques SOLUCIONADO al título de tu pregunta eso no es correcto, si ya tienes la solución entonces publícala debajo en la zona de respuestas

Comment: Ohh Mil disculpas, vi que ya lo editaste. Ahi lo agrego. 

Gracias Aprendiz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema fue solucionado.

El error era que al declarar las variables dentro de las funciones de igual manera (todas a,b,c,etc), estas hacían que la función principal actuara de manera no esperada.

Se soluciono declarandolas con `LET` / `CONST`.